Flask Blueprint Routes Returning 404 and 401 in Unit Tests
I'm trying to run unit tests on my Flask application, but I'm encountering issues with my blueprint routes returning 404 and 401 status codes. I have two blueprints, user_bp and noticias_bp, which I register in my Flask app. Here is my project structure:
project/
│
├── app/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── user.py
│   ├── noticias.py
│
└── tests/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_app.py


user.py:
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify

user_bp = Blueprint('user_bp', __name__)

@user_bp.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify({"message": "User Index"}), 200

@user_bp.route('/profile')
def profile():
    return jsonify({"message": "User Profile"}), 200


noticias.py:
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify

noticias_bp = Blueprint('noticias_bp', __name__)

@noticias_bp.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify({"message": "Noticias Index"}), 200

@noticias_bp.route('/latest')
def latest():
    return jsonify({"message": "Latest Noticias"}), 200


test_app.py:
import unittest
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from user import user_bp
from noticias import noticias_bp

class TestApp(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Configurar a aplicação Flask para testes
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        CORS(self.app)
        self.app.secret_key = '2002'
        self.app.register_blueprint(user_bp, url_prefix='/user')
        self.app.register_blueprint(noticias_bp, url_prefix='/noticias')

        # Configurar o cliente de teste
        self.client = self.app.test_client()

    def test_user_blueprint_registration(self):
        # Verificar se o blueprint do usuário está registrado na aplicação Flask
        self.assertIn('user_bp', self.app.blueprints)

    def test_noticias_blueprint_registration(self):
        # Verificar se o blueprint de notícias está registrado na aplicação Flask
        self.assertIn('noticias_bp', self.app.blueprints)

    def test_user_blueprint_routes(self):
        # Testar se as rotas do blueprint do usuário estão acessíveis
        response = self.client.get('/user/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        response = self.client.get('/user/profile')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_noticias_blueprint_routes(self):
        # Testar se as rotas do blueprint de notícias estão acessíveis
        response = self.client.get('/noticias/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        response = self.client.get('/noticias/latest')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()


Errors I'm facing:
FF.Hello world
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_noticias_blueprint_registration (__main__.TestApp.test_noticias_blueprint_registration)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ferre\Projects\Portal-de-Noticias\backend\user_registration\test_app.py", line 25, in test_noticias_blueprint_registration
    self.assertIn('noticias_bp', self.app.blueprints)
AssertionError: 'noticias_bp' not found in {'user_bp': <Blueprint 'user_bp'>, 'noticias': <Blueprint 'noticias'>}

======================================================================
FAIL: test_noticias_blueprint_routes (__main__.TestApp.test_noticias_blueprint_routes)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ferre\Projects\Portal-de-Noticias\backend\user_registration\test_app.py", line 38, in test_noticias_blueprint_routes
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200

======================================================================
FAIL: test_user_blueprint_routes (__main__.TestApp.test_user_blueprint_routes)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ferre\Projects\Portal-de-Noticias\backend\user_registration\test_app.py", line 33, in test_user_blueprint_routes
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 401 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.049s

FAILED (failures=3)


It seems like the noticias_bp blueprint is not registered correctly and my routes are returning 404 and 401 errors. What could be causing these issues? How can I resolve these errors to make my tests pass?
Thanks in advance for any help!
